# What is the probability that the Red ﬁsh are the ﬁrst species to become extinct from the pond? A Combinatorial Approach

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

A pond contains 3 distinct species of ﬁsh, which we will call the Red, Blue, and Green ﬁsh. There are r Red, b Blue, and g Green ﬁsh. Suppose that the ﬁsh are removed from the pond in a random order. (That is, each selection is equally likely to be any of the remaining ﬁsh.) What is the probability that the Red ﬁsh are the ﬁrst species to become extinct from the pond?

**I came across this answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/904862)**

> Answer: Consider an fish tank with n black fishes and m white fishes,  the total number of outcomes = (n+m)!.  Number of ways the last fish is white is m.(m+n-1)!.  Thus the probability is $\frac{m.(m+n-1)!}{(m+n)!} = \frac{m}{m+n}$.
> In your problem, if there are r red fishes, b blue fishes, and g green fishes,
> Based on the same reasoning as (a), the probability that the Blue fish and the Green fish are the last species to become extinct is $\frac{b}{r+b+g}\text{ and }\frac{g}{r+b+g}$ respectively. **Furthermore, the conditional probability that the Blue fish are the second species to become extinct, given that Green fish is are the last species in the pond, is$ \frac{b}{r+b}$.** Similarly, the conditional probability that the Green fish are the second species to become extinct, given that the Blue fish are the last remaining fish in the pond, is $\frac{g}{r+g}$
> Let R be the event that the Red fish are the first species to become extinct in the pond,RBG denote the event that the Red fish first become extinct, followed by the Blue fish, then by the Green fish, and RGB denote the event that the Red fish first become extinct, followed  by the Green fish, then by the Blue fish. Then we can obtain

> $P(RBG) = P(G-last)P(RBG/G-last) =\frac{g}{r+b+g}\frac{b}{r+b}$

> $P(RGB) = P(B-last)P(RGB/B-last) =\frac{b}{r+b+g}\frac{g}{r+g}$
> Finally, we can compute the probability that the Red fsh are the first species to become
> extinct in the pond by adding these two.

In the answer, the author used a combinatorial approach when there are only $2$ types of fish. I understood much of the argument except this :

**Furthermore, the conditional probability that the Blue fish are the second species to become extinct, given that Green fish is are the last species in the pond, is$ \frac{b}{r+b}$.**

I am not quite able to visualize why this is true, especially the part in which the green fish are plain ignored. I think ignoring can be a bad idea because the left over green fish can contribute to the number of permutations. Can someone please give a combinatorial argument to prove this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ignore the $g$ green fish. we have $ r$ red and $b$ blue fish. (Based on the existing argument) What's the probability that the last fish is $b$?

Comment: @CalvinLin It should be $\frac {b}{r+b}$. But, what I am trying to know ( in a rigorous way ) is why it's ok to ignore the green fish?

Comment: We can ignore the $g$ green fish because, for all the possible arrangement of $g$ green fish, the probability that $b$ is last is the same.

Comment: @CalvinLin I do seem to get it. But, just to make it firmer : How do we know that : P(blue second last | green last) = P(blue second last | only red and blue).?

Comment: In the sample space where green is last, segment/group them according to where the $g$ green fish are (and we have g-1 choose r+b+g-1 such groups). In each group, there is a bijection with the r choose r+b sequences. If we ignore the g's in the group, then this bijection shows us that and the probability that b is second last in this group, is the probability that b is last in the r+b sequence.

Comment: @CalvinLin Would you please like to write an answer in which this bijection is a bit more clearly stated? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The probability that the blue fish are the second-to-last species, given that the green fish are the last species is simply the probability that the blue fish outlast the red fish.  If you want a combinatorial argument, think of permutations of the red and blue fish where the last fish is blue.

It obviously doesn't matter where we put the green fish.

**EDIT**

Suppose we have $g$ green fish and $p=b+r$ purple fish.  Take any permutation of the green and purple fish.  Now consider the number of ways to color $b$ of the purple fish blue and $r$ of them red.  This can be done in $\binom{b+r}{b}$ ways. Now consider the number of ways to color $b$ of them blue and $r$ red if the last one must be blue.  There are $\binom{b+r-1}{b-1}$ to do this.  If all permutations are equally likely, we get that the probability that the last fish is blue is $\frac b{b+r}$.  Since this is true for every permutation of the green and purple fish, and every permutation of the green, red, and blue fish corresponds to a unique permutation of the green and purple fish, we see that the probability that the blue outlast the red fishes is the same, no matter what we assume or don't assume, about the green fishes.

Comment: I get that the probability that the blue fish are the second-to-last species, given that the green fish are the last species is simply the probability that the blue fish outlast the red fish. But is this probability independent of the number of greens that might come in between?

Comment: @MathMan Absolutely.  The green fish have no effect whatsoever on the relative positions of the red and blue fish.  It's something like rolling two dice: what's the probability that you roll a $6$ before a $7$?  It's $\frac5{11}$, because there are $5$ ways to roll a $6$ and $6$ ways to roll a $7$.  We don't care about the other $25$ rolls.

Comment: Could you please give me some hints towards a more rigorous argument for the same? Although, I get what you say, but to be able to precisely say this, I would be very grateful. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The probability that red will be the *first* to have *all* removed is the same as the probability that red will be the *last* to have *any* removed. This is because reversing the order of removal is a bijection. For any permutation $\sigma$ that results in red being the first to have all removed, we can take $\sigma'$ to be that permutation in reverse order. Since all the fish in the tail of $\sigma$ are non-red, all the fish in the head of $\sigma'$ are non-red.  Under this bijection, the claim

> Furthermore, the conditional probability that the Blue fish are the second species to become extinct, given that Green fish is are the last species in the pond, is $\frac b{r+b}$.

becomes

> Furthermore, the conditional probability that the Blue fish are the second species to have any removed, given that Green fish is the first species to have any removed, is $\frac b{r+b}$.

There are a total of $b+r$ non-green fish, and all of them are equally likely to be the first non-green fish removed, so the probability that the first non-green fish is blue is $\frac b{r+b}$.